# Second-Largest Integer

Tags: integer

I am trying to program on my TI calculator a program the finds the second-largest integer in a sequence using a one pass algorithm (Not by sorting the list).
Can anyone help with TI calculator program for this or just a simple program in general.

Answer (score 1):

The *algorithm* is a simple one:

```
# Start by getting the first two numbers (in order).

if num[1] > num[2]:
    set first to num[1]
    set second to num[2]
else:
    set first to num[2]
    set second to num[1]

# Process every other number.

for each index 3 through size(num) inclusive:
    # If greater than current highest, insert at top.

    if num[index] > first:
        second = first
        first = num[index]
    else:
        # Otherwise if greater than current second highest, insert there.

        if num[index] > second:
            second = num[index]
```

It basically maintains the two highest numbers in the list and replaces them, as needed, when comparing all the other numbers. It's a one-pass algorithm as requested.

You may also want to consider what behaviour you want when there are duplicates in the list. For example, the list `1 1 2` will currently give you `1` as the second highest integer in the list. If that's not acceptable, there'll have to be small tweaks made to the algorithm.

In any case, what I've given you there is a good starting point, and translating that to your TI calculator language is a task I'll leave to you.